# How can a change variable name within for loop to get lists("divide") corresponding to 'slide1' and 'slide2'

Tags: r

Suppose have a dataframe like this :-

```
df<- read.table(text="groups names
1       a
1       b
1       c
1       d
2       e 
2       f
2       g
2       h
", header=T)
```

I divided this data frame into two groups by using

```
split_groups <-split(df, df$groups)
```

Then I used for loop to obtain the overlapping lists of split_group[[1]] and split_group[[2]] as follows:

```
slide <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
    slide[[i]] <- rollapply(split_groups[[i]][,2], width =2,by=1, matrix, align="right")
}
```

And obtained this :-

```
slide[[1]]:
a
b
**b**
c
**c**
d

slide[[2]] :
e
f
**f**
g
**g**
h
```

then I divided `slide[[1]]` and `slide[[2]]` into lists of equal rows:

```
divide <- split(slide[[1]], cumsum(seq_len(nrow(slide[[1]])) %%2  == 1))
```

and obtained divide[[1]] = a,b ; divide[[2]] = b,c and so on.
Similarly from slide[[2]], divide[[1]] = e,f and so on.

I want to rbind `divide[[1]]` from split[[1]] and split[[2]] ie set1 = a,b,e,f in the form of list or dataframe. 
Similarly divide[[2]] from split[[1]] and split[[2]] ie set2= b,c,f,g. 
ie

```
set1:
a
b
e
f

set2:
b
c
f
g
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this: (The `slide` output is different than it was showed in the post)

```
 divide1 <- split(slide[[1]], cumsum(seq_len(nrow(slide[[1]])) %%2  == 1))
 divide2 <- split(slide[[2]], cumsum(seq_len(nrow(slide[[2]])) %%2  == 1))
 nm1 <- paste0("set", 1:2)
 Map(function(x,y,z) setNames(data.frame(c(x,y)),z), divide1, divide2, nm1)
 #$`1`
 #  set1
 #1    a
 #2    b
 #3    e
 #4    f

#$`2`
#  set2
#1    b
#2    f
```

Or if you have more list elements in `slide`, you could do:

```
 divide <- lapply(slide, function(x) split(x, cumsum(!!seq_len(nrow(x)) %%2)))
 divN <- unlist(divide)
 lstN <- split(unname(divN), substr(names(divN),1,1))
 nm1 <- paste0("set", seq_along(lstN))
 Map(function(x,y) setNames(data.frame(x),y), lstN, nm1)
 #$`1`
 #  set1
 #1    a
 #2    b
 #3    e
 #4    f

 #$`2`
 # set2
 #1    b
 #2    f
```